# C# ping with another mac

Tags: c#

I tried doing this but I receive many errors since I'm new to C# coding.

My actual purpose is I want to ping a static ip which is constantly receiving data from a temperature sensor. I want to see the data from my home and save the data.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    public class Pinger
    {

        public static int GetPingTime(string host)
        {

            int dwStart = 0, dwStop = 0;

            // Create a raw socket.
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
              SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);

            // Get the server IPEndPoint, and convert it to an EndPoint.
            IPHostEntry serverHE = Dns.GetHostByName(host);
            IPEndPoint ipepServer = new IPEndPoint(serverHE.AddressList[0], 0);
            EndPoint epServer = (ipepServer);

            // Set the receiving endpoint to the client machine.
            IPHostEntry fromHE = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPEndPoint ipEndPointFrom = new IPEndPoint(fromHE.AddressList[0], 0);
            EndPoint EndPointFrom = (ipEndPointFrom);

            // Construct the packet to send.
            int PacketSize = 0;
            IcmpPacket packet = new IcmpPacket();
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                packet.Type = ICMP_ECHO;
                packet.SubCode = 0;
                packet.CheckSum = UInt16.Parse("0");
                packet.Identifier = UInt16.Parse("45");
                packet.SequenceNumber = UInt16.Parse("0");

                int PingData = 32;
                packet.Data = new Byte[PingData];

                for (int i = 0; i < PingData; i++)
                    packet.Data[i] = (byte)'#';

                PacketSize = PingData + 8;

                Byte[] icmp_pkt_buffer = new Byte[PacketSize];
                int index = 0;
                index = Serialize(packet, icmp_pkt_buffer, PacketSize, PingData);

                // Calculate the checksum for the packet.
                double double_length = Convert.ToDouble(index);
                double dtemp = Math.Ceiling(double_length / 2);
                int cksum_buffer_length = Convert.ToInt32(dtemp);
                UInt16[] cksum_buffer = new UInt16[cksum_buffer_length];
                int icmp_header_buffer_index = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < cksum_buffer_length; i++)
                {
                    cksum_buffer[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(icmp_pkt_buffer,
                      icmp_header_buffer_index);
                    icmp_header_buffer_index += 2;
                }

                UInt16 u_cksum = CheckSum(cksum_buffer, cksum_buffer_length);
                packet.CheckSum = u_cksum;

                // Now that we have the checksum, serialize the packet again.
                byte[] sendbuf = new byte[PacketSize];
                index = Serialize(packet, sendbuf, PacketSize, PingData);

                // Start timing.
                dwStart = System.Environment.TickCount;
                socket.SendTo(sendbuf, PacketSize, 0, epServer);

                // Receive the response, and then stop timing.
                byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[256];
                socket.ReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, 256, 0, ref EndPointFrom);
                dwStop = System.Environment.TickCount - dwStart;
            }

            // Clean up and return the calculated ping time in seconds
            socket.Close();
            return (int)dwStop;
        }

        private static int Serialize(IcmpPacket packet, byte[] buffer,
          int packetSize, int pingData)
        {

            // (Private method for serializing the packet omitted.)
        }

        private static UInt16 CheckSum(UInt16[] buffer, int size)
        {

            // (Private method for calculating the checksum omitted.)


    }
    public class PingTest
{

    private static void Main()
    {

       int GetPingMS(string hostNameOrAddress);

    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
    return Convert.ToInt32(ping.SendAddress.RoundtripTime);

// How to call this function (IP Address).
MessageBox.Show ( GetPingMs("122.198.1.1"));

    }



    }
```

Comment: That's all great and such, but what's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: "i receive many errors" - do you maybe want to *tell* us what these errors *are*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Stackoverflow uses the concept of "gamification." One of the fun parts of the game is trying to figure out what the actual question is! Wait...I'm being told that's actually not part of the game...

Answer (score -1):

use This Sample because the Sample from Microsoft is not ready tu use...

http://www.codeplanet.eu/tutorials/csharp/4-tcp-ip-socket-programmierung-in-csharp.html?start=4

in this "german" Tutorial is the full code avaible for sending IP.

```
packet.Type = ICMP_ECHO;  --> ICMP_ECHO must be set with a number (8) manual
{
    private static int Serialize(IcmpPacket packet, byte[] buffer, int packetSize, int pingData)
            {
                // (Private method for serializing the packet omitted.)
            }
            private static UInt16 CheckSum(UInt16[] buffer, int size)
            {
                // (Private method for calculating the checksum omitted.)
        }
}
<--mustbe create by your own 
    private static void Main()
        {
           int GetPingMS(string hostNameOrAddress);
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        return Convert.ToInt32(ping.SendAddress.RoundtripTime);
    // How to call this function (IP Address).
    MessageBox.Show ( GetPingMs("122.198.1.1"));
        }
```

I think you never reach this Messagebox because you jump aut with 
"return Convert.ToInt32(ping.SendAddress.RoundtripTime);"

set the meassagebox befor the return..